# Token while authentification in a web java application using web services

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, authentication, token

i have a web service "authentification" which gives users acces to their accounts, after getting the login and the password. but i need to generate a token to use it instead of login & password while consuming web services !

i have no idea about this token ?
what is it ?
how to use it ?
any tutorials to help please?

i'm using JAVA to develop my Client application , and my web services are REST

Comment: It is hard to say what do you mean by "token", but there are more options if you want to pass user credentials in web service call. Does "token" maybe refers to UsernameToken? If the answer is positive, then please check your web service client documentation on how to generate and pass UsernameToken in WS-Security header.

Comment: really, i have no idea ! in fact, they told me that i have to generate a token from login and password, to pass it in the url instead of login&password ( because i'm going to consume REST web services )

Comment: Well, they have to explain a little more what are expecting as "token" :-(

Answer (score 0):

I guess by saying token, you mean an encrypted string. So the end user, who uses this token, will not know what is the credentials(username and password). You may try AES encryption. This will give you an encrypted token for the given plain text(in your case may be username|password). When user provides this token, you can decipher it and authenticate the user.

Refer http://aesencryption.net/